# How to Only use Kestrel in .NET Core

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel

Creating a new .NET Core app from Visual Studio 2019 makes my app run with iisexpress when debugging. I plan to deploy to Linux and thus only want to use Kestrel throughout for both Developing on my Win7 machine and then deploying to the Linux Server using Self Contained Deployment (which I believe WILL use Kestrel).

What do I need to do to configure my app to only use Kestrel and not IIS when I am developing on Win7?

EDIT: When I click down arrow and change from IIS Express to app name I get this error

[image: dev certs error]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2019 there is a green > button which you use when you run the application. Right now the button's text is "IIS Express". Click on the down arrow which allows you to change that and select "YourAppName".

You can also to this in command line:

Navigate to the folder where your application's DLLs are and run `dotnet YourAppName.dll`.

Comment: Can you run the Visual Studio as Administrator and try again?

Comment: Did you try to run `dotnet YourAppName.dll` in the command line?

Comment: It is working now partially from VS...I can navigate to https://localhost:5001. However I cannot replace localhost with machine name as in (assuming name is win7): https://win7:5001. I get this site cannot be reached. Is that something that the `dotnet` command line can fix?

Comment: So you want to access your application by navigating to http://win7:5001?

Comment: Edit the `hosts` file located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and add a new line there: `win7 127.0.0.1`. Save the file, run your application and navigate to http://win7:5001

Comment: The `https://` part got removed from the url. So actually it would be the computer and domain name so `https:// win7.int.com:5001`. I want to do this so that I can access the site from a different machine. If it doesn't work on my own machine this way I doubt it would on another. So I still need to edit the hosts file? If so then that means I have to do that for every .NET app?

Comment: What you want should be addressed in another question. Your initial question was about Kestrel and IIS Express. I suggest to ask another one.

Comment: Here is url of new question if you want to take a stab at it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609957/net-core-access-site-externally